How can I use enum in CPP and connect it with Cython?
In CPP folder, I have MyWork.h and MyWork.cpp. In Cython folder, I have MyWork.pxd and MyWork.pyx.
Now I want to use enum in CPP and then connect it in Cython as follow
[MyWork.h]
enum Task {
    REGULAR,
    DEV,
    MARKETING
};

class _MyWork {
   _MyWork();
   int get_my_work_id(Task value)
}

Let's skip the MyWork.cpp because I don't think it matters in this case.
[MyWork.pxd]
cdef extern from "MyWork.h":
    cdef enum _MyWork:
       REGULAR,
       DEV,
       MARKETING

    cdef cppclass _MyWork:
       _MyWork()
       int get_my_work_id(Task value)

[MyWork.pyx]
cdef class Triangle:
    def __cinit__(self):
        # STH
        pass

    def get_my_work_id(self, Task value):
        # What should I do here?
        pass

  

I think I know how to write it in .pxd but how do I write in .pyx?

https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html#structs-unions-enums

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cython+enums, too. Also, _MyWork is a reserved identifier in C++.

@UlrichEckhardt your link doesn't show any question

Could you guys show me?

I can't confirm that, it shows 23 questions for me.

To connect an enum defined in CPP with Cython, you need to properly declare and use the enum in your Cython .pxd and .pyx files.

@Hil Could you show me how did you it in .pxd and .pyx?

If you want to use the enum from Python then declare it as cpdef enum instead of cdef enum. Beyond that you just call get_my_work_id(value) - you pass the value like any type. I don't really understand the confusion.

This is what you need
In C++, an enum is a type safe way to define a set of named constants. In Cython, you can use C++ enums in your Cython code by including the C++ header file that defines the enum, and then using the enum values in your Cython code.
Here's how I would use a C++ enum with Cython:
Step 1: Define the C++ enum
Create a C++ header file (e.g. my_enum.h) that defines the enum:
// my_enum.h
#ifndef MY_ENUM_H
#define MY_ENUM_H

enum class MyEnum {
   VALUE1,
   VALUE2,
   VALUE3
};

#endif  // MY_ENUM_H

Step 2: Include the C++ header file in your Cython file
In your Cython file (e.g. my_cython_file.pyx), include the C++ header file:
#cython: language_level=3

cdef extern from "my_enum.h":
cdef cppclass MyEnum:
    MyEnum VALUE1
    MyEnum VALUE2
    MyEnum VALUE3

Note: The cdef directive is used to declare a C++ class or struct in Cython.
Step 3: Use the enum in your Cython code
You can now use the enum values in your Cython code:
cdef MyEnum my_enum = MyEnum.VALUE1
print(my_enum)  # prints 0 (the underlying integer value of MyEnum.VALUE1)

Note: In Cython, enums are treated as integers, so you can perform arithmetic operations on them.
Step 4: Compile and link your Cython code
cythonize my_cython_file.pyx -a -i my_enum.h -o my_cython_file.so

This will generate a shared library (my_cython_file.so) that you can use in your Python program.
Using the enum in Python
To use the enum in Python, you'll need to create a Python wrapper around your Cython code. You can do this by creating a Python module (e.g. my_module.py) that imports the Cython module:
# my_module.py
import my_cython_file

my_enum = my_cython_file.MyEnum()
print(my_enum)  # prints 0 (the underlying integer value of MyEnum.VALUE1)

That's how you do it.

Downvoted because this is a needless complicated hacky reimplementation for something that Cython supports directly. There's absolutely no need to create a fake cppclass

The method here would have been an old workaround to support C++ enum class from when Cython didn't support enum class enums. It's now outdated because Cython does support enum class enums, so definitely isn't the simplest and clearest way to do it. It's also not necessary because the code in the original question uses a regular enum rather than an enum class enum. Most of it isn't wrong (although quite a few of the details are) but it isn't really good advice any more.
